# Why am I getting a segmentation fault error with the following code?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm a Python programmer studying C. I receive a segmentation fault on the final `printf()` of the following code. I'm sure it has something to do with the expression but I'm not sure what the problem is. Unfortunately, the expression works in Python so I'm unable to get a more specific error message. I'm using the GCC compiler in Debian.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

  int n;

  printf("Enter a two-digit number: ");
  scanf("%d",n);

  printf("The reversal is: %d\n", (n % 10) * 10 + (n / 10));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: scanf needs a pointer to n.

Comment: `scanf("%d",n);` should be `scanf("%d", &n);`  forgot `&`

Comment: you know segmentation fault is not in printf  but in scanf function call. Due to invalid memory access. Read [Segmentation fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault)

Answer (score 2):

Pass address of `n` to `scanf()` as

```
scanf("%d", &n);
```

Answer (score 0):

try `scanf("%d",&n);`

it has no way to put anything into n unless it has a pointer to n

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a pointer to an int as the argument to `scanf`, not the int itself; `&n` rather than just `n`.